# changing plotly mouse controls behaviour

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotly

I would like to know whether it's possible to change how the mouse mouse navigation works in `Plotly` (for python)

In `matplotlib` you could enable the `pan/zoom` mode to control the figure with just 2 mouse buttons. Use the **left button** to scroll along the graph in any direction. Use the **right button** to scale the figure either vertically or horizontally.

[image]

Whereas in `plotly`, every time I need to zoom in onto something I need to select a specific region and then there is no easy way to zoom out just a little bit.. you have to reset the view. To move the view along the X/Y axis you have to hold a `SHIFT` button.. It feels like navigation in plotly requires too many additional button clicks (either on a keyboard or a mouse)

[image]

Therefore I would like to know if there is either a built-in way or some kind of mod available for `plotly`, to enable the same (or better) navigation as in `matplotlib`. Particulary, I am interested in zoom behavior of plotly so it is not based on the region-zoom. Maybe mouse wheel zoom at least or something similar..

Comment: Zooming with the mouse wheel can add the following settings For details, `config = dict({'scrollZoom': True});fig.show(config=config)` please refer to the [reference](https://plotly.com/python/configuration-options/#enabling-scroll-zoom).

Comment: I am not sure if you can scale the figure either vertically or horizontally in Plotly as in the matplotlib.

Comment: thank you! Zoom fix is nice!